# Are there any job sites that allow you to filter jobs by hourly wage?

Tags: job-search

I'm looking for a job site (like indeed) that allows you to filter jobs by **hourly** wage. Sites I've found so far have salary or yearly wage (or no wage at all) listed, which isn't really helpful for my job search

I want to clarify I'm not looking for advice. I ask that you remember that everyone's job search is different and making assumptions about my goals is not helpful or respectful. This especially applies to people who have never looked for a blue collar job

Comment: @JoeStrazzere it isn't that simple. Many jobs are part time so yearly earnings are based on a number other than 2k. Filtering by "salary" estimate is entirely worthless in my context

Comment: Filtering by hourly rate is entirely worthless in any context as some jobs are part time or have special considerations.

Comment: You can calculate the hourly rate by knowing the yearly and weekly hours, both should be available on most sites

Comment: @SolarMike comments that make bad assumptions about my job search goals are entirely worthless

Comment: @DanK I appreciate your attempt to give me advice, but what you suggest really isn't practical in my situation. The reason I kept my question short is I didn't really want/need anything other than an answer to my specific question

Comment: @Shane hourly rate really doesn’t matter, even if you had the had the hourly rate that won’t be the same as what you actually take after deductions. If your on salary the best you can work with is monthly rate, again this won’t be same after deductions. Hours don’t matter on salary if you work 35 or 40 hours your monthly is the same. This is why all job sites don’t list an hourly rate as it’s irrelevant. Annual you can work out your monthly rate and then from their work out your deductions.

Answer (score 2):

Most job sites support this (including LinkedIn, Indeed, StackOverflow careers, ...).

It is typically implemented by having an **optional** field when submitting a job ad. The employer can choose whether or not to disclose pay. It will perhaps come as no surprise that many employers choose not to disclose it. The filter is therefore useless, since it will throw out the majority of high paying jobs. Of course, if your point of interest is *whether* an employer discloses pay, rather than the actual pay itself, that's a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

indeed.com provides for searching for only "hourly" jobs.

Use the following link to see how the "What" search box is filled in.

https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Hourly